# Animate object out of the screen and keep it there

Tags: android, android-animation

How can I move an object out of the screen?

This is how I move the TextView from under the screen into the screen.

slide_up_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="500" android:fillAfter="true"/>
</set>
```

This is how I move it out of the screen:

slide_down_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="100%" android:duration="500" android:fillAfter="true"/>
</set>
```

But the TextView appears again. Why?

Comment: If you don't want your testview in screen after animation then i think you should remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because it renders it again after the animation and will actually place the `TextView` to its default position from the screen/layout.

**solution:**

You need to add a listener and set the visibility of your `TextView` to gone or invisible at the end of the listener.

```
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
               You_text_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. Despite this I wonder if this is the right way. After the animation the TextView goes back, we just hide it, so it's basically a trick, isn't it?

Comment: @erdomester it is not a trick but a solution, you cant really manipulate the view visibility in animation so yes we need to set its visibility after the animation.